# Laravel 5.2 $fillable

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

Let's say, my model has the following DB structure:

```
name:string
last_name:string
```

And I wish to update the model, with this `$request->input()` array given:

```
name => 'Quinn',
last_name => 'Daley',
middle_name => 'Phill'
```

I would get an error message, because it would try to update the `middle_name` field, which does not exist in the DB.

So here is my question:
**How can I make it so only existing fields are updated?** Without using the `protected $fillable` property.

*Edit: the reason I don't want to use $fillable is that I don't want to list all the existing fields from the database. What if I have a large model with 50 fields in it? Isn't there a possibility to only accept parameters that exist in the model DB from the `$request->input()`*?

**UPDATE**

There is a cleaner solution using `$model->getAttributes()`:

```
$user->update($request->only(array_keys($user->getAttributes()))
```

This solution is also better if you are using a different `$connection` for the model, which was my case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `input()` or `all()`, you can use the `only()` or `except()` methods on the request to limit the fields. For example:

```
$user = User::find(1);

$user->update($request->only(['name', 'last_name']));
// or
$user->update($request->except(['middle_name']));
```

#### Edit

If you want to get the column names of the table, you can do this using `Schema::getColumnListing($tableName);`. So, in this case, your code would look something like:

```
$user = User::find(1);

$user->update($request->only(Schema::getColumnListing($user->getTable())));
```

Comment: The reason I don't want to use $fillable is that it would take too much to list all the fields.

What if I have 50 fields in the model. Would it be `$request->only(['field1', 'field2', ... 'field50']`?

Answer (score 0):

protected $fillable will be required, if you are using create or update function. however, I think you solve it in this way without using the protected $fillable property.

```
$yourmodel = YourModel::find($id);
$yourmodel->name = $request->input("name");
$yourmodel->last_name = $request->input("last_name");
$yourmodel->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use fillable array in this way:

```
// in your model

/**
 * Get only available fields
 *
 * @param  array  $input
 * @return array
 */
public function filterFields(array $input)
{
    $fields = $this->fillable;

    return array_filter($input, function ($v, $k) use ($fields) {
        return in_array($k, $fields);
    }, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH);
}
```

And filter data from `$request->input()`;
Also you can make middleware for this perpose.