# Laravel 5.2 Model $fillable gets ignored?

Tags: php, laravel, mass-assignment

I have a simple Model `IsolatedQuery` which consists of a `name` and `query` field. I have defined those two fields in the `$fillable` property of the model. The IsolatedQueryController@store looks like this:

```
public function store(IsolatedQueryRequest $request)
{
    IsolatedQuery::insert($request->all());

    session()->flash('flash_message', 'Isolated Query succesvol opgeslagen');

    return redirect('iq');
}
```

For completeness, here is the Model's source (it is as little as I described it)

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class IsolatedQuery extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'query'
    ];
}
```

The `IsolatedQueryRequest` only requires both `name` and `query` to be filled with any value.

When calling the `store` method with a given name and query value I get the error: `SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '_token' in 'field list'`.

It's obvious a `_token` field gets send with the request but I'm a bit baffled why it's trying to store it with the actual SQL query as it's not listed in the `$fillable` array.

Why is it getting mass assigned?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel 5.2 $fillable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34864666/laravel-5-2-fillable)

Comment: @bishop It's not a duplicate, this question asks why it's happening and the one you link to doesn't answer that. Also, this question is about using the fillable proprty, and the other one is about not using it.

Comment: It's not a duplicate indeed. I want to apply `$request->all()` is it should be possible, rather than calling `$request->only`. If I wanted that I wouldn't have to defined the mass assignable list with `$fillable`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use Query Builder's method `insert`. It doesn't check the `fillable`. 
You should use the `create` or `update` method of Eloquent. 
Please, read the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent#inserting-and-updating-models).

Also, you may pass input data to `construct` or `fill` method of Eloquent. After that you may use the `save` method.

Comment: Howly mowly.. I've completely looked over it... Thanks! +1A

Comment: One may also use [`Eloquent::fill()`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/tree/master/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L428-L454), though IMO `create` and `update` express the intent more clearly.

Comment: so what you will do when you have a large data to insert it once? looping through it and use create method is not efficient at all